# decoding mp3: lame vs mpg123 performance on android

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, mp3, decoding

I'm looking for the fastest MP3 decoding library for android (NDK). Does anyone know which one of them will give me a result (PCM raw samples) the fastest?
LAME or mpg123?

Thanks!

Comment: The only way to answer this question is with an experiment. The result will depend on your particular device and a bunch of other factors.  Because of this, it's not really a suitable question for SO

Comment: Well I understand this is strongly dependent of the specific device, but I guess the performance relations between the two should more or less remain across the devices, isn't it?